# Enable javascript alerts Dialog in xamarin Android CrossWalk webview

Tags: javascript, xamarin.android, dialog, alerts

java-script Alerts not working in Crosswalk Web-view

this is what I tried:

```
    protected override void OnXWalkReady()
    {
        fa = this;

        var view = new RelativeLayout(this.BaseContext);
        var mp = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
        xwv = new Org.Xwalk.Core.XWalkView(this.BaseContext, this);
        view.AddView(xwv);
        this.AddContentView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mp, mp));
        XWalkPreferences.SetValue("enable-javascript", true);
        xwv.SetResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(xwv));
        xwv.SetUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(xwv));
        xwv.AddJavascriptInterface(new Foo(this, xwv), "Foo");
        xwv.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }
```

JavaScript alerts working by defaults in Android studio when using Crosswalk but not Xamarin..

### update

```
class Foo : Java.Lang.Object
//, Java.Lang.IRunnable
{
    Context context;
    XWalkView xwv;
    Activity activity;
    public Foo(Context context, Org.Xwalk.Core.XWalkView xwv)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
        this.xwv = xwv;
    }


    [Org.Xwalk.Core.JavascriptInterface]
    //[Export]
    /// [JavascriptInterface]
    [Java.Interop.Export("Run")]
    public void Run(string text, string id)
    {

     Toast.MakeText (context, text,ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
   }
```

### html index file:

```
   <body>
   <div  onclick="clicked()">Say Hello</div>
    <script>
        function clicked() {
        alert();
         Foo.Run('this test from js', "1");
        }
    </script>
   <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
   </body>
```

this is my HTML elements in the index HTML file i tried to show alert and select tag but it didn't worked.

Comment: I tested your code and the java-script Alerts not working in Crosswalk Web-view with the error message like this: "Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?"       

            You can solve this problem by a work around: raise a alertDialog in your Foo() , and inject the method whenever you want to use alert in your javascript.

            BTW, Could you please post your code of Foo class? So that I can test it for you.

Comment: thank you very much i update my question

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and the java-script Alerts not working in Crosswalk Web-view with the error message like this: "`Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?`"

You can solve this problem by a work around: raise a alertDialog in your `Foo()` , and inject the method whenever you want to use alert in your javascript.

I wrote a demo based on your posted code, you can try it:

1 export a `Alert()`method in Foo to display an alertDialog

```
   protected override void OnXWalkReady()
            {
                var fa = this;

                var view = new RelativeLayout(this.BaseContext);
                var mp = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent;
                var xwv = new Org.Xwalk.Core.XWalkView(this.BaseContext, this);
                view.AddView(xwv);
                this.AddContentView(view, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mp, mp));
                XWalkPreferences.SetValue("enable-javascript", true);
                xwv.SetResourceClient(new XWalkResourceClient(xwv));
                xwv.SetUIClient(new XWalkUIClient(xwv));
                xwv.AddJavascriptInterface(new Foo(this, xwv), "Foo");
                xwv.Load("file:///android_asset/index.html", null);
            }
        }

        class Foo : Java.Lang.Object
        //, Java.Lang.IRunnable
        {
            Context context;
            XWalkView xwv;
            Activity activity;
            public Foo(Context context, Org.Xwalk.Core.XWalkView xwv)
            {
                this.context = context;
                this.activity = activity;
                this.xwv = xwv;
            }


            [Org.Xwalk.Core.JavascriptInterface]
            //[Export]
            /// [JavascriptInterface]
            [Java.Interop.Export("Run")]
            public void Run(string text, string id)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, text, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }

            [Org.Xwalk.Core.JavascriptInterface]
            //[Export]
            /// [JavascriptInterface]
            [Java.Interop.Export("Alert")]
            public void Alert(string text)
            {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.SetTitle("Alert Message");
                alert.SetMessage(text);
                alert.SetPositiveButton("OK", (senderAlert, args) =>
                {
                    //Toast.MakeText(context, "OK!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                });

                Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
                dialog.Show();
            }
```

2 Call Alert() method whenever you would like to show alert in index.html and pass a string as parameter to set what message you want to alert.

index.html:

```
<body>
   <div  onclick="clicked()">Say Hello</div>
    <script>
        function clicked() {
            Foo.Alert("This is alert message");
            Foo.Run('this test from js', "1");
        }
    </script>
   <select>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
 </body>
```

Comment: thanks but i solve the issue no need for all that check this project:
https://github.com/mirzanove/Xamarin.Android.XWalk

Comment: your solution is good for one case but i needed solution that works for all cases it turn out javascript alerts wont work if you create webview dynamically but if you handle it from the layout it will works thank you ...

Comment: Well, glad it helped. And by googling this issue, I found it is a popular problems for many people. I think your solution will help them. That's very good.

Comment: yes i had to hire a freelancer to give some advice to how to solve it and he fixed it..
so i create a project in GitHub to help others ... thank you sir